# defining max and min yaxis values after using ax.set_yscale('log') in matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I generated the following chart:

[image: Regular Chart]

Then wanted to adjust the vertical axis of the first subplot to show in logscale, 
so did `ax.set_yscale('log')`.

This produces the following chart:
[image: yaxis in logscale]

The question is how do I set max and min levels to show in this new logarithmic yscale?

Comment: ```ax1.set_ylim([8, 20])```. But i don't think a logscale is a good approach with this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same as you do on any other scale, use [`ax.set_ylim()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim)

If you want to set it to the range 8,20 as you have above, then pass those two limits to `set_ylim`:

```
ax.set_ylim(8, 20)
```

Comment: but is there a way of getting the max and min of this new scale?

Comment: what do you mean? the min and max of the data, or of the y axis? For the latter, you can use `ax.get_ylim()`

Comment: I mean the min and max of the rescaled data that is generated with ax.set_yscale('log'). 
With  ax.get_ylim() you get the max and min in the original scale of the data.

Comment: the data doesn't change by switching to logscale. All that changes is how you are viewing it. so a data point with a y value of 10 before swicthing to logscale will still be at `y=10` afterwards.

Comment: what worked in the end for me was ax.axis('tight') but that wasn't specifically my question. Approving your answer and +1 for the ax.get_ylim().